# How Destructuring Works In Function Parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I tried to search on this but no luck so far.  I've looked at destructuring info on the web.  I don't understand though this partcular pattern of destructuring.

```
const App = ({todos, actions}) => (
  <div>
    <Header addTodo={actions.addTodo} />
    <MainSection todos={todos} actions={actions} />
  </div>
)
```

what is {todos, actions} doing here in the function's param definition?  What todos and actions is it pulling from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call `App` like `App({todos:10,actions:{addTodo: addTodoFunction}})` in the `App` function the arguments `todos` and `actions` get assigned to `10` and `{addTodo: addTodoFunction}` respectively. So `actions.addTodo` becomes `addTodoFunction`. More at [Object Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring).

Comment: ok did not know you could call functions like that.  Basically it's the same thing as <MyComponent someProp={someValue} />.  If your react component is an ES6 class, then I guess under the hood it would send it like this:  export default class MyComponent({someProp{){  ....... }

Comment: There's nothing special about calling functions "like that" - it's just a function call with an object as its only parameter. The magic is in the function definition, which is now able to destructure the passed object. Before ES6, you would do `function(obj) { var todos = obj.todos, actions = obj.actions; ... }`

Comment: got it, thanks!  I didn't realize there was destructuring with function param calls like that.  I get it now.

Comment: yea somehow I missed this section "Pulling fields from objects passed as function parameter".  Cool.

Answer (score 0):

Those are the props that React passes to your component:

```
<App todos={...} actions={...} />
```

So you could write your component without destructuring like this:

```
const App = (props) => (<div>
  <Header addTodo={props.actions.addTodo} />
  <MainSection todos={props.todos} actions={props.actions} />
</div>)
```

React passed the props to your component as an object, and destructuring extracts properties from an object, so it is a shortcut!

You could also destructure your props in two steps:

```
const App = (props) => {
  const { todos, actions } = props
  return (<div>
    <Header addTodo={actions.addTodo} />
    <MainSection todos={todos} actions={actions} />
  </div>)
}
```

Notice that in this last case you have to use curly braces and `return` explicitly because there are multiple statements in your arrow function.